# Using RDF to model normal sentences

Tags: nlp, rdf, semantic-web, reification

I'm trying to somehow store everyday sentences -- or rather the information expressed by the sentences -- in a (semi-)structured manner. Right now, I'm exploring the feasibility of RDF for that. I'm not familiar with RDF enough to assess if this is suitable way to go. While I'm sure that there will be some form of information loss, I cannot say it it would be acceptable for practicable purposes.

Obviously, sentences like "Bob ate the cake" can be directly mapped into subject-predicate-object triple (although I'm don't know how to properly address the tense of the predicate):

```
:Bob :ate :Cake .
```

I then came across reification that converts a single triple as 4-triple graph representing a statement with a subject, predicate and object node. This allows to reflect statements over statements, e.g., "Alice thinks that Bob ate the cake.":

```
_:stmt1 rdf:type rdf:Statement .
_:stmt1 rdf:subject :Bob .
_:stmt1 rdf:predicate :ate .
_:stmt1 rdf:object :Cake .
:Alice :thinks _:stmt1 .
```

So far so good. However, everyday language has so many more constructs. Here are just some of the more obvious (to me):

- Conditions: "If Alice tells the truth, Bob ate the cake."
- Auxiliary verbs: "Alice can bake cakes."
- Clausal complements: "Alice likes to eat cake."
- Negation: Given the Open World Assumption, the absence of a triple `:Bob :ate :Cake .` is ambigious. In many practical settings I would argue that making negation explicit is important.
- Disjunction: "(Either) Alice or Bob ate the cake." Most people do not reliably distinguish between OR and XOR in everyday language.
- Quantifier: "Most people like cake.", "Very few people hate cake."

I assume some can be realized in a relatively straightforward manner. For example, "Alice thinks that Bob did not eat the cake" could be represented as

```
_:stmt1 rdf:type rdf:Statement .
_:stmt1 rdf:subject :Bob .
_:stmt1 rdf:predicate _:predA .
_:predA :term :eat
_:predA :tense :past
_:predA :negated :true
_:stmt1 rdf:object :Cake .
:Alice :thinks _:stmt1 .
```

This might also allow to express simple adverbs (e.g. "Bob quickly ate the cake") by having a triple such as

```
_:predA :advmod :quickly
```

On the other hand, reification alone quickly increases the number of required triples. I guess you can push it to the extreme and consider output of an dependency parser as a set of triples, e.g.:

```
nsubj(thinks, Alice)
ccomp(thinks, ate)
nsubj(ate, Bob)
dobj(ate, cake)
...
```

but I cannot see this truly useful when it comes to query the graph or infer from it.

I read a couple of scientific papers that focus on converting text into RDF, but most of them focus the extraction of simple facts. Apart from that, I couldn't find any good resources on how useful/expressive/practical RDF is to represent knowledge beyond simple factoids.

Comment: You already analyzed the problem very well. RDF is made of triples, so you are limited by this. A sentence indeed is made of much more information than just the sequence of words/tokens. You should maybe start from the the other direction and think how to use the data later. For example, what kind of data, what kind of queries. Apart from that, there is nothing else one could do. Even in any other data format you'd basically have to solve the same problems. Indeed, n-ary relations with blank nodes would be nice.

Comment: Another data model would be a property graph. At least here you could attach properties directly to nodes and edges. Maybe it's also worth to have a look at this. Query languages exist, though there is no well-defined semantics like in RDF/OWL

Comment: Last comment, [NIF](http://persistence.uni-leipzig.org/nlp2rdf/) format is so far state-of-the-art in RDF NLP stuff

Comment: @AKSW Great comments! I've read the NIF paper. The focus seems to be on a standardized annotation of text w.r.t the output of NLP tools. I'm generally looking for a way to store unstructured raw text (e.g., form posts, tweets) in some (semi-)structured form that retains the core information (<== that's admittedly extremely vague) to allow for search, linking, inference, etc. Right now, I'm not even fixed on a data representation, but some form of graph seems intuitive. I also looked into properties graphs - may be a good alternative indeed.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem as of 2020. Anyway, it is
unrelated to whether you use property graph or triple
store. Based on my personal research, a triple store can do
everything property graph does, with more query capabilities and
more theoretical performance both in terms of query times and disk
space use.

Comment: If you already looked into POS tagging, dependency trees, link grammar, co-reference resolution, entity extraction, you are at the state-of-the-art (AFAIK).